# SQL Server 2008 CONTROL SERVER permission

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The sp_password sproc in sql server 2000 only required membership in the db_accessadmin  db_securityadmin database roles and membership in the securityadmin server role to allow a user to change passwords w/o knowing the old password. However in sql server 2005/2008 the BOL says a user now needs the "CONTROL SERVER" permission to do this. 
What powers exactly does the CONTROL SERVER permission give a user?

Update: I found this:

> CONTROL SERVER is a new permission as of SQL Server 2005 and it grants the same access as being a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.
>   - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/brian_kelley/archive/2009/02/24/detecting-when-a-login-has-implicit-access-to-a-database.aspx

Update:
Turns out the documentation is wrong. Just like SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2008  sp_password still only seems to require membership in the db_accessadmin & db_securityadmin database roles and membership in the securityadmin server role to allow a user to change passwords w/o knowing the old password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the listing of the specific securables affected by CONTROL SERVER on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717.aspx).

Comment: I think a had found that page, but i missed that table - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a complete description of the security implications of CONTROL SERVER in comparison with sysadmin on this blog: ["CONTROL SERVER vs. sysadmin/sa: permissions, system procedures, DBCC, automatic schema creation and privilege escalation - caveats"](http://www.insidesql.org/blogs/andreaswolter/2013/08/control-server-vs-sysadmin-sa-permissions-privilege-escalation-caveats).

It is important to note, that a principal with CONTROL SERVER can easily elevate his permissions to sysadmin which is shown there as well.

Plus a list of all procedures that still need "sysadmin"-server role.